# Close in red box is being hidden by overlay

Tags: css

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sNv2X/7/) - thanks @haxxxton

HTML sample

```
  <div class="icon-btn">
     click me    
</div>

<div class="sidebar-panel">
    <div class="close" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;background: red;position: relative; top: 0; left: -50px;z-index:9200">
        x
    </div>
  <div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid #eee;">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

 <div id="overlay"></div>
```

The red box is acting as close button. The issue is that it is hidden under the overlay. Have tried positioning, z-index. Also tried to create extra div to wrap the sidebar panel but because of no width defined, it does not hold everything inside.

Inline style you see in code was for testing to see if it actually shows up.

**Update**

CSS

```
.sidePanelOpen .icn-close-trend{
  z-index: 9100;
}

.icn-close-trend {
  background: url('../img/icon-close.png') no-repeat;
  width: 28px;
  height: 27px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -70px;
  padding: 35px;
}
```

Still does not help at all - it is still hidden

Answer (score 0):

Your close box has an inline style that make is to -50px to the left and that pushes it under the black box. Around `-35px` makes it flush.

Reference:

```
<div class="close" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;background: red;position: relative; top: 0; left: -35px;">
```

I would highly recommend not using inline styles for this and instead applying those directly to the "close" class.

Also, for your reference, z-index values don't work unless you also declare the position (relative/absolute/fixed). Not that it is actually needed in this case.

Comment: sorry but I m not clear with your explanation..so -50px to left will make it appear on top of overlay?

Comment: -50px to the left makes it appear underneath the overlay. The overflow solution will work too (if you want it on top of the overlay).

Comment: if i remove overflow, the sidebar with listing will get long, so need to have scroll on the sidebar panel

Comment: Then do as suggested and change -50 to -35.

Comment: Or add a div inside the shelf, and make that scrollable.

Comment: @Benjamin - Which shelf? You refer to inside sidebar panel div?

Answer (score 0):

`.sidebar-panel` has the property `overflow-y: auto` which seems to be pushing your red `.close` div below the shelf. If you kill `overflow-y: auto`, `.close` sits atop the shelf nicely.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/26wdr/

If you're concerned about having the content of the shelf be scrollable, I'd recommend using a container `div`with a fixed height inside the shelf and making that scrollable.

eg http://jsfiddle.net/K5F9D/

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?